# Do I need a Router when having a UTM?

Tags: router, vlan

Hello my Question is really simple, do I need to have a Router when using a UTM (Unified Thread management)?

Currently I want something like this:

```
Modem <-> UTM <-> HP ProCurve <-> VLAN1
                              <-> VLAN2
```

Would this setup be possible or would i need to put a router in front of the vlans?

I heard that several UTM's could do the routing, too. Also this setup would be great since i could have VLAN2 connect to VLAN1 but VLAN1 not to connect to VLAN2.

Answer (score -1):

If your UTM also does routing, then I dont see why not. Keep in mind though that that is a single point of failure/compromise. They get in there or take that down and everything (in/out/between) those networks is gone till you get it back up